# How do I increase the value of one variable integer according to a set formula which includes another (constantly increasing) class variable?

Tags: ruby, variables

I have two class variables, `@ticks` and `@dings`, both of which which I want to begin at `1`.

Other functions occasionally add various amounts to `@ticks`, and `@dings` will increase by `1` each time `@ticks` meets *or surpasses* `(@dings * 100) + (@dings * 10)`.

I want to perform `dings += (number of times met or surpassed)` immediately after any operation which causes `@ticks` to meet or surpass the current value of `(@dings * 100) + (@dings * 10)` one or more times.

Is this an appropriate solution?

```
def increment_ticks
  while @ticks >= (@dings*100) + (@dings*10)
  @dings += 1
  end
end
```

and I just call `increment_ticks` each time `@ticks` is added to (or add `increment_ticks` in the appropriate spot in all functions which add to `@ticks`).

Comment: Obviously, your variables live (or need to live) in an object. That object should have its central method for `@ticks` incrementing, and that method should handle `@dings`, too. Problem solved.

Comment: Yes, they are members of the same class. So, should I make a class method which provides for every circumstance in which `ticks` would increase, and declare the condition for `dings`' increase there as well?

Comment: You're talking about class variables and methods, but you seem to mean instance variables and methods. Or do you actually mean class variables? Please clear that up.

Comment: Sorry, I'm kind of new to this. I have a class whose members should all have their own `ticks` and `dings` variables, with all `ticks` and `dings` controlled by the same formula. SO `ticks` and `dings` are instance variables, since they are different for every instance of the class. But the formula controlling them is a class method, since it's the same for all instances of the class. Correct?

Comment: I don't understand that the formula needs to be a variable... Can't you just put the formula in a instance method and use instance variables in that formula?

Comment: Then what's a class method, if not a method available to all instances of a class? Is it just that it's also available to children of that class, where instance methods are not?

Comment: @user2493615 Class methods are those which you send to a class (e.g. `Foo = Class.new; Foo.bar`), whereas instance methods are those which are sent to an instance of a class (e.g. `Foo = Class.new; foo = Foo.new; foo.bar`).

Comment: What do you mean "send to"? In `fluffy.kittens` is `kittens` being sent to `fluffy`?

Answer (score 6):

Since `@dings` are the same as `@ticks` divided by 110 rounded down, the easiest way to do this is not increase `@dings` at all, but simply calculate it each time you you want it.

Your class can have a `dings()` method that returns the number of `@ticks` divided by 110.

Comment: Thanks, this gave me a whole new perspective.

Answer (score 0):

Since dings and ticks are strictly related, you should create a class that stores the dings and ticks.

The whole point of this solution is to add an extra level of data protection for the `@ticks` and `@dings` variables in order to force the use of the method `increment_ticks` their class `A` provide. This way you are sure the `@dings` variable is always consistent.

Here's an example:

```
class A 

    def initialize( x = 0 )
        @ticks = x
        @dings = 0
    end

    def increment_ticks( a )
        @ticks += a
        @dings += 1 if @ticks >= (@dings*100) + (@dings*10)
    end

    def ticks; @ticks; end
    def dings; @dings; end

end
```

The problem you are facing is the following: you have a variable ( `@ticks` ) which gets modified by multiple other functions, but you want to update the value of another variable ( `@dings` ) strictly linked to the first one ( `@ticks` ).

You can solve this issues by lightening the main class and create a proper class to handle this logic ( as shown above ).

When you initialize the class you can give the starting number of ticks. The number of ticks can be modified only by calling `increment_ticks` ( this is the key point of this solution ), therefore you are sure that every single time `@ticks` is incremented, the:

```
@dings += 1 if @ticks >= (@dings*100) + (@dings*10)
```

check is called.

Inside your main class you can easily instantiate:

```
@a = A.new( 0 )
```

and then call:

```
@a.increment_ticks( 123 )
```

in every function that needs to increment the ticks. Finally you can retrieve their values by:

```
@a.ticks
@a.dings
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'm still trying to wrap my mind around this. Question: by "main class", do you mean the outermost, non-user specified class (Class)? Also, I'm not grasping the point of maing a separate class just for this. Data protection from what?

Comment: @user2493615, by *main class* I mean the class where you have your current `@ticks` and `@dings` ( not the one of my answer, the one in your questions ). Data protection means that you cannot alter `@ticks` or `@dings` arbitrarily, but only using the `A` public interface ( the method `increment_ticks`.